# OED Appeals: Antedatings of "DIY"

Tags: etymology, abbreviations, initialisms, oed-appeals

The OED has made a [public appeal](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-needs-you-announcing-the-new-oed-appeals/) for help in tracing the history of some English words, [including](http://public.oed.com/appeals/diy/):

> ### DIY
>
> abbreviation *earlier than 1955*
>
> *DIY* is of course an abbreviation of *do it yourself*, and both terms refer to the carrying out of a task by oneself, especially around the home. The entries for these terms are currently being revised by *OED* editors. The earliest use of *do it yourself* as a phrase found so far dates from the nineteenth century (without the later associations with home improvement):
>
> > **1845 Richard H. Barham *Ingoldsby Legends* (1905) 288 If it’s business of consequence, *Do it yourself!***
>
> By 1910, the phrase being used as an adjective:
>
> > **1910 *Popular Science Monthly* May 493 At the Boston Tech a method has been in vogue for long that is there deemed highly satisfactory—it is known as the ‘do-it-yourself method’.**
>
> But our evidence for the initialism *DIY* currently goes back only as far as 1955:
>
> > **1955 Titusville (Pa.) Herald 22 July 8/4 (advt.) DIY means ‘Do It Yourself’ and you can.**
> >
> > **1955 *Practical Householder* Dec. 203/1 A central pool such as a ‘D.I.Y. Club’ from which..tools can be hired is the obvious advantage.**
>
> We suspect that earlier evidence for *DIY* may exist. Can you beat our DIY efforts?

Answer (score 3):

I've found one antedating of some five or six months, and another from the previous year.

---

*[Popular Science](http://books.google.com/books?id=LiYDAAAAMBAJ&pg=RA1-PA283&dq=%22D%20I%20Y%22%20%22do%20it%20yourself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zMCaUKGxGsr64QSb_IGYAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true)* magazine (Feb 1955 - Vol. 166: No. 2 - Page 283) has a cut-out-and-post coupon has this address:

> McCall's DO-IT-YOURSELF PATTERNS
>   DEPT. DIY • DAYTON 1, OHIO

[image: McCall's DO-IT-YOURSELF PATTERNS DEPT. DIY • DAYTON 1, OHIO]

---

And better, from a 1954 advert.

*[The Argus](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/23449475?searchTerm=%22D%20I%20Y%22%20%22do%20it%20yourself%22&searchLimits=sortby=dateAsc#pstart1772447)* newspaper (Melbourne, Victoria: 1848 - 1956) Friday 5 November 1954 p. 9 advertising:

> One of the most useful tools now helping to popularise "D.-I.-Y." is the Black & Decker All Purpose Unit, shown at right.

[image: One of the most useful tools now helping to popularise "D.-I.-Y." is the Black & Decker All Purpose Unit, shown at right.]

---

Can anyone else find something earlier?